# How can I prefix the output of each match in grep with some text?

Tags: bash, unix, grep

I have a file with a list of phrases

```
apples
banananas
oranges
```

I'm running `cat file.txt | xargs -I% sh -c "grep -Eio '(an)' >> output.txt"`

What I can't figure out, is that I want the output to contain the original line, for example:

```
bananas,an
oranges,an
```

How can I prefix the output of grep to also include the value being piped to it?

Comment: Could you please do lemme know if my answer helped you here.

Answer (score 1):

This should be a task for `awk`, could you please try following.

```
awk '/an/{print $0",an"}'  Input_file
```

This will look for string `an` in all lines of Input_file and append `an` in them too.

Answer (score 0):

Solution with `sed`:

```
sed '/an/s/$/,an/' intput_file
```

This finds lines that match the pattern `/an/`, and appends `,an` to the end of the pattern space `$`.

Answer (score 0):

Use awk instead of `grep`:

```
$ awk -v s="an" '                          # search string
BEGIN {
    OFS=","                                # separating comma
}
match($0,s) {                              # when there is a match
    print $0,substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)     # output
}' file
```

Output:

```
banananas,an
oranges,an
```